# Can you extend controller in Nodejs/Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I've a route A that uses controller 1.

```
#A
router.get("/:id", require("./user_get"));
```

I want to use same logic for route B but only serve different html.

```
#B
router.get("/:id", ????);
```

I could copy paste code from `user_get` to new file. But I was wondering is there a way to extend it. Can I change res.render value somehow if I simply include `user_get` in new file.

Comment: if you send the response or any headers in `./user_get` then you can't

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is separate out whatever action you're doing in `userGet` into a middleware.

```
const userGet = (req, res, next) => {
  // whatever you use to get the user
  // if your user getting is async the following lines would of course need to be in your `.then`
  res.locals.user = user
  next()
)}
```

Notice the middleware signature -- a function with `req`, `res`, and `next`, the use of `res.locals`, and the call to `next` at the end.

Then you'd write your route handlers:

```
const routeOneHandler = (req, res) => {
  res.render('templateForRouteOne', { user: res.locals.user })
}

const routeTwoHandler = (req, res) => {
  res.render('templateForRouteTwo', { user: res.locals.user })
}
```

and update your routes like so:

```
// route one
router.get('/:id', userGet, routeOneHandler)

// route two
router.get('/:id', userGet, routeTwoHandler)
```

If the concept of `middleware` and `next` is new to you, I recommend checking out the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html), or see the info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369121/how-do-i-pass-data-returned-from-a-controller-to-express-router/49369439#49369439).